# Trying to take IP and remove periods to use an int else where on the page

Tags: javascript

I found this code to get the IP:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
function getip(json){
  alert(json.ip); // alerts the ip address
}
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip"> </script>
```

But I don't entirely understand it.  I want to try to find a way to take the variable json.ip and turn it into a global integer that can be called in any JS on the page.  Such as IP:25.454.545.34  -> 2545454534.

Comment: If you get an IP address where `454` and `545` are among the parts, something's gone very wrong...

Comment: Just know that in doing this is a one-way conversion (and the converted IP address is no longer guaranteed unique).  This may or may not matter, depending on how you plan to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're receiving the IP address as a string:

```
var ip_no_dots = ip.replace(/\./g, "");
```

Just beware that that means the IPs `12.1.2.3` and `1.21.2.3` will both result in `12123`.

If you want to take the IP and turn it into one big int, you'll need to be careful to multiply the earlier numbers to avoid introducing errors (those dots are there for a reason). Here's one way:

```
var ip, match, ipInt;

ip = '1.2.3.4';

match = /^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/$.exec(ip);
if (match && match.length == 5) {
    ipInt = (parseInt(match[1], 10) * 256 * 256 * 256)
            + (parseInt(match[2], 10) * 256 * 256)
            + (parseInt(match[3], 10) * 256)
            + parseInt(match[4], 10);
    display(ipInt);
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/oqete4)